# How to get element from array in new line? react

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping over data which returns an array of elements. In some cases tests.databases returns two database names and I would like to create a new line

Comment: can you show your array structure (unitTestData) and visual formation of your requirement please?

Comment: Just updated it in my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Map the array of database names to include a break element. Or you can wrap each name in its own div with style, whatever you need really.

```
{props.unitTestsData &&
  props.unitTestsData.map((test) => (
    <div key={test.id} className="Table UnitTestsGrid">
      <div>{test.id}</div>
      <div style={{ wordWrap: "break-word" }}>{test.unit_test_name}</div>
      <div style={{ wordWrap: "break-word" }}>
        {test.databases.map((el) => (
          <Fragment key={el}>
            {el}
            <br />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          mainColor
          changeHandler={(e) => updateUnitTestSelection(e, test)}
          data={{}}
          id={test.id.toString()}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Comment: You know me better than I know myself haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'}}>{test.unit_test_name}</div>
<div style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'}}>{test.databases}</div>
```

Use `span` instead of `div`

Comment: haha all good, yeah it didn't work without the break word

Comment: use `style={{display: 'block'}}`